# Getting guid's from prefabs in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Kinda specific question, I'm working on a script which will retreive all unused materials and textures from the project and show/delete them. I went by path of GUID parsing from a scene file, but encountered a couple of problems, which, if can't be solved, make this solution impossible.

1) In scene ".unity" file, when a prefab is used, it contains only this prefab's GUID, but prefab itself contains child objects - how can they be accessible?
E.g:

```
Prefab:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  serializedVersion: 2
  m_Modification:
    m_TransformParent: {fileID: 0}
    m_Modifications:
    - target: {fileID: 444956, guid: 6a526c61069224c92930d52849053cbe, type: 2}
      propertyPath: m_LocalPosition.x
      value: 0
      objectReference: {fileID: 0}
```

And as well in the Project view there are no children more than second hierarchy level:
[image]

What I want to do - somehow to get all the materials AND textures used by, for example, "Ceiling" in the scene. Taking in account that "Blue" prefab is loaded at runtime, not present in the scene, so I can only take the root guid from the monobehaviour.

2) Even if I somehow get all the used the materials, how to properly get textures used by them without accessing renderer of a gameobject, just these:

[image]

I know it's a bit messy question, so please, ask if something is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need this: [AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(string guid);](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath.html)

1. You have parent prefab -> you can extract all `guid` of its children
   -> you can find children prefabs -> you can extract all `guid` of their children and so on ...
2. You have a material -> you can extract all `guid` of its used materials 
   then you can use `AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(string guid)` to get
   all the used texture paths. `Resources.Load<Texture2D>(string assetPath);` can be used to get the actual textures.
3. I'm afraid accessing prefab loaded at run-time is not possible. Just
   like shader. If you load a shader at runtime and you forget to add
   it to `AlwaysIncludedShaders` you will get the pink stuff
   only on the built version but not when playing in the Editor. Even Unity can't solve that problem. At least not yet.

Some more methods you may be interested in:
[EditorUtility.CollectDependencies();](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.CollectDependencies.html)
[EditorUtility.CollectDeepHierarchy();](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.CollectDeepHierarchy.html)

Comment: As for the p1 - I can't actually, see the "Blue" gameobject and prefab in project view, it's a single prefab with one guid, but I came to a conclusion that what I want is impossible in this way.

But great thanks for these methods, you mentioned, this might be the other better way of doing things for me! :)

Comment: okay, CollectDependencies is Godlike, can confirm that it does everything we needed, choosing prefabs assigned to public fields, their dependencies (mats, textures etc), AND is superfast, comparing to the previous way it was done. thank you, mate, you saved my night ^_^